# Crystal Reports Word wrap cuts in the middle of a word

Tags: crystal-reports, word-wrap

I have an 3rd party tool that uses Crystal Reports to generate reports.
In essence it just uses an odbc connection to the internal DB.

Now some of the fields that I put on my report are large text fields. To accommodate this I set the field to "can grow" and word wrap is on.
While the growing part works fine it is the wrapping that acts weird.

For some reason in both the preview of the designer or the actual generated report itself it cuts words when it reaches the side of the page instead of moving the whole word to the next line.

Any thoughs what this could be (or if it is a bug)?
The text field is formatted/interpreted as HTML

[image]

Comment: Check your version, this is a reported issue with 13.0.19.2312. See: [CRforVS 13.0.19.2312 word wrap in textboxes](https://answers.sap.com/questions/165935/crforvs-130192312-word-wrap-in-textboxes.html)

Comment: This looked promissing.. but I downgraded to SP18 from SP20 and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the version I was unable to find a solution/workarround.
Hence I solved it in my data itself by changing the data before feeding Crystal Reports